# How can I get the character at the cursor in a C# console application?

Tags: c#, console, cursor

**I know how to set the cursor** to a specific point in the console with *SetCursorPosition* or *CursorLeft* and *CursorTop* together. That's not a problem.

**But**, how can I get the value of that point? Isn't there a thing like *Console.Cursor*? So I can get the character at that position? Maybe something like:

```
char c = Console.GetCharAtCursor();
```

No luck?

Comment: Could you clarify as to what value you are trying to get? Are you trying to get the value of a string or number that you're pointing to or the coordinates of the pointer?

Comment: The post is edited. Can you read it again? And if you have any other way to do that, please share it.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, you have to read the entire console buffer as a two dimensional buffer, and use the cursor's X and Y coordinates as an index into that buffer. See:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(
    IntPtr consoleHandle,
    out CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO consoleScreenBufferInfo);
```

You can read about the buffer structure here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682093(v=vs.85).aspx

**Update:**

If you're interested in using console APIs for game writing, someone wrote space invaders for the console (actually powershell) but all of the APIs are managed code, not script. He has sprite/path  routines etc - the source is over on http://ps1.soapyfrog.com/2007/08/26/grrr-source-code-including-invaders/

Comment: But would it be fast/useful if I'm programming a console game?

Comment: @UfukSarpSelçok: If you are programming a console game, I suggest you keep your own copy of the screen buffer in a 2D-array.

Comment: @UfukSarpSelçok I updated my post with a link to a good console library for game stuff (sprites, paths etc)

Comment: Your answer is correct, but not complete. In order to find the character at a particular position, you need to offset the X and Y coordinates by the values in the `srWindow` field. That is, `bufferX = X + bufferInfo.srWindow.Left`.

Answer (score 0):

'CursorLeft' and 'CursorTop'  have getters so you can just read them: `var cleft = Console.CursorLeft`

Comment: `CursorLeft` and `CursorTop` have getters but they return the position and not the character at the position.

Answer (score 0):

According the answer [from the MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/7f81a977-85e8-40c4-a8c7-27c63a43e29d/get-a-character-from-cursor-on-c):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(
    IntPtr hConsoleOutput, 
    [Out] StringBuilder lpCharacter, 
    uint length, 
    COORD bufferCoord, 
    out uint lpNumberOfCharactersRead);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct COORD
{
    public short X;
    public short Y;
}

public static char ReadCharacterAt(int x, int y)
{
    IntPtr consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(-11);
    if (consoleHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        return '\0';
    }
    COORD position = new COORD
    {
        X = (short)x,
        Y = (short)y
    };
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(1);
    uint read = 0;
    if (ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(consoleHandle, result, 1, position, out read))
    {
        return result[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return '\0';
    }
}
```

Applied it looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Clear();

        Console.CursorLeft = 0;
        Console.CursorTop = 1;
        Console.Write("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

        char first = ReadCharacterAt(10, 1);
        char second = ReadCharacterAt(20, 1);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not like the long answers posted here for my simple application, so I figured a workaround for this – I stored the entire console buffer in a 2D array and then just indexed in the array. Worked for my application (generating icicles in console):

```
            char[,] array = new char[20, Console.BufferWidth];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if (i > 0 && array[i - 1, j] == ' ')
                    {
                        array[i, j] = ' ';
                        Console.Write(' ');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int x = getRandom.Next(10);

                        switch (x)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                array[i, j] = ' ';
                                Console.Write(array[i, j]);
                                break;

                            default:
                                array[i, j] = 'x';
                                Console.Write(array[i, j]);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```