# Get the console background at a particular position

Tags: c#, .net, console

I have an extremely simple Console application written in C#. It is very easy to change the background and foreground colors when printing text, but I am wondering if there is an easy way to determine the background and foreground colors at a particular position.

It's not an essential feature, so I'm not interested in P-Invoke, etc. If it can't be done in 1 minute, then I'll just leave it.

**EDIT**

I'm looking for something like

```
Console.GetBackground(0,0);
```

I don't see anything like that in the MSDN documentation, but I'm hoping I may have missed something simple.

Comment: Did you ever find _any_ programming task, no matter how small, that can be done within one single minute?

Comment: Typing `Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;` takes me less than one minute.

Comment: Your question was about _getting_ not setting, wasn't it?

Comment: I asked in the hopes of uncovering an already-built .NET feature of which I was unaware. Seems pretty clear that there is no such feature, and I do not care to roll one myself. Thanks for the attention, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in feature in .NET capable of providing the foreground and background colors previously used at an arbitrary location in the console.

Kudos to offlinehacker for the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042859/get-the-console-background-at-a-particular-position/12042961#comment16083314_12042961) providing a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the Windows API documentation. While it's possible this could have provided a solution, the implementation was too complicated for me. (I abandoned the effort, but I may try again if the cost-benefit ratio changes.)

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor.aspx) for getting foreground color and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.backgroundcolor.aspx) for background. And use `setcursorposition` for changing console position.

Hope it works.

Comment: `Console.Foreground` and `Console.Background` do not keep track of the character-by-character colors. Once set, or reset, the change is global. Setting the cursor position will not update these values to the settings last used at that position.

Comment: I found out that [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might help. Seems like there's no .net api avalible for that task, so you have to use native api from `kernel32.dll`. Example how to import one of those api's can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790280/how-can-i-get-the-character-at-the-cursor-in-a-c-sharp-console-application). This is not as simple as first I taught it might be.

Comment: +1 for that last comment - very interesting and helpful API. But too involved for my very unecessary requirements. Will keep it in mind if this comes back around, though. Thanks! (You might want to edit your comment to show the correct usage of Foreground and Background, however)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could make a class that gets the width and height of the console, maps every possible coordinate, then keeps track of every color change and the coordinate at which the color was changed. That way, you could just traverse to the point you are interested in, and
see what color the console was then.

It would not be a terribly long thing to implement, I think... thought there might be better ways.

Comment: Not a bad idea, and I would use it if I really needed the feature, but the time commitment is far too high. Thanks though.